# lonpress inspecting element on appium inspector

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have to inspect an element after long pressing it on Appium inspector. 
To perform any action, there are three options
1. tap
2. sendkeys
3. clear

How to get any element inspected after long press? 'Tap' does not work. it just taps the element. whats the solution for longpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in inspector right now.

But here is a tip: you can run your code in test and call `driver.getSource()` right after a long press, and print output to console. Then grab any XML formatter and inspect your element.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will surely try this method.